# How to convert an uploaded file to a DataFrame in Shiny apps

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I'm following the [File Upload Control](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/fileInput.html) tutorial from the Shiny site.

[image]

This code allows to load a CSV file, and it automatically renders a table from the uploaded file:

[image]

The issue is that I can not access this table as a dataframe for further processing.

Comment: How is this too broad? *"can not access this table as a dataframe for futher [sic] processing"* is well-defined and clear. Please everybody, just because you may feel the OP did not do much research does *not* mean this is too broad. None of you have (documented) [tag:shiny] experience, so there's no reason to believe you see something significant that I did not (am I'm nowhere near a guru).

Comment: What is *"Shany"*? Do you mean *"Shiny"* (as in the body)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, I meant Shiny. Just edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set up a reactive block to give you the data:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
        accept = c(
          "text/csv",
          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
          ".csv")
        ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata <- reactive({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    req(input$file1, input$header, file.exists(input$file1$datapath))
    read.csv(input$file1$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(mydata())
    mydata()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now anywhere else you need to do something with the new `data.frame`, just use `mydata()`. (My only changes were to move some lines into a new reactive block, shorten the `renderTable` block, and use `req(...)` instead of the clunkier `is.null` method.)

---

Some additional notes:

- Often in `shiny` apps, it can be very useful for a reactive block to do one thing well, such as "get data", "plot data", "adapt/change data". It is with this that I broke down the original single block of "read a file and then render it" into two blocks of "read a file" (providing data to one or more consumers) and "render it".
- This needs to be balanced with *reactivity*, meaning that the more blocks that rely on other blocks, the more likelihood there is to what I call "hyper-jittering" of app components. For instance, if block "B" relies on "A", and block "C" relies on both "A" and "B", then you might see this update schedule:

  1. "A" updates (for some reason)
  2. "C" updates based on "A"
  3. "B" updates based on "A"
  4. "C" updates based on "B" (i.e., two updates from a single change; this produces user-visible double-changes, and for some plots might include a finite *time* delay doubled).
- Combining both bullets: breaking up "read and render" into "read" and "render" seems reasonable. If you have data-munging to do (removing/adding columns, filtering out rows, etc),

  - if you never need the original/raw data then this mutation should probably be done in the "read" stage;
  - if you ever want to reference the raw data at the same time as the changed data, then you might need "read", "update", and "render" stages/code-chunks;
  - even if you never need to reference the raw data, if any of the mutation relies on user-defined values (`selectInput`, `numericInput`, etc), then you should probably go with "read", "update", "render" stages so that you don't have to re-read the data every time the user changes one of the other fields